# EaselJS, Canvas, Bitmap image low quality and registration point not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap, coffeescript, easeljs

I just started using EaselJS for a project I'm working on and I'm a bit stuck with the Bitmap Class.. What I do is add a 3000 x 4000 image to the canvas / stage and let the user scale and rotate it. Mainly I'm using the following function:

```
@width = 3000
@height = 4000
@scale = 0.2

@bitmap.setTransform( 0, 0, @scale, @scale, 200, 0, 0, @width*@scale/2, @height*@scale/2 )
```

This all works except for the registration point. The number given to the function is half the image width / height, so should be good. But the rotation is still not from the center..

Also I'm looking for a way to increase the quality of this Bitmap or the Stage.. When the Bitmap is scaled to 0.2, the image isn't visible at all, just a bunch of big blocks / pixels..

Hope someone can help me out here,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stupid mistake, my canvas was scaled up so the quality was low even if the image wasn't scaled.

The width and height **attributes** define the canvas **resolution**.

The **css style** width and height define the **size** of the canvas.

For everybody having problems with quality, you can oversample the canvas:

```
<style>
  canvas {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
  }
</style>

<canvas width='400' height='200' />
```

Source:
http://blog.headspin.com/?p=464